# 'Line2D' object has no property 'density'

Tags: python, seaborn, cdf

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.randn(200)
kwargs = {'cumulative': True}
sns.distplot(x, hist_kws=kwargs, kde_kws=kwargs)
```

When I rant the code above it did give a correct histogram figure but did not give its associated kde fit and returned AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'density'.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. What version of seaborn and matplotlib are you using? Are you sure you are showing the complete code that raises this Exception?

Comment: 0.9.0 for serborn and 3.2.2 for matplotlib @DizietAsahi i am sure that's the entire code

Comment: @Diziet Asahi 0.9.0 for serborn and 3.2.2 for matplotlib i i am sure that's the entire code

Comment: Did you try to upgrade to the latest versions? The maintainers constantly work to improve the existing code; trying to debug old versions usually isn't a productive investment of time. (Note that  for the latest version, `distplot()` has been replaced by `histplot()` for your use case.)

Comment: That did work thanks @JohanC